What is the best software for using latex in Windows offline, bearing in mind that I'm still learning?
What is the best software for using latex in Windows offline, bearing in mind that I'm still learning?

Welcome. // I‘m using MikTex and TexMaker. However, that doesn’t matter too much. More important is reading a good book or two about LaTeX in parallel.

What do you mean with best?

You might also take a look at TeXnicCenter (editor) which has mnay useful TeX specific feature (like online help and a menu of math symbols).  You will still neeed a LaTeX compiler.

You need to read an introduction.
You need a software to edit *.tex files. This kind of software is called editor and there are many.
You need a LaTeX installation, either Texlive or MikTeX.
Using your editor you write a file, let's say "hello.tex"
Using your LaTeX installation you produce "hello.pdf" from "hello.tex".
